# Canadian applying for a French working holiday visa: How long in advance?

Tags: visa, working-visas, france

I'm having a hard time finding information about this online. I'm Canadian and I want to apply for a working holiday visa in France. They say that you can only apply up to three months in advance. I want to travel Asia for 4-5 months before arriving in France.

If I apply in June and ask for my visa to start in September but I actually end up arriving in France in November. Will they refuse my entry? Or will my visa only be valid for 10 months instead of the original year because I got there two months late?

Also, if anyone has any personal experience about how long it took them to receive an answer once they went through the application/ interview process, that would be great.

Comment: The easiest solution is to simply work in France and *then* travel in Asia for 4-5 months. That way you don't have to worry about the embassy taking too long to issue your visa.